# Tricky Element Collection

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays (`numpy` 1-D array):

```
A = [7 7 7 7 1 8 8 8 8 7 2 2 3 3 5 5 5 2 8 8 8]
B = [50 20 32 91 92 93 35 72 41 42 43 63 64 85 86 56 26 27 28 89 69]
```

where `A` is a permutation of repetition of numbers, and for evey element in `A` there is a unique `ID` associated with it which is stored in `B`. For example, the first element `7` in `A` has `ID=50`, the second element `7` in `A` has `ID=20`, and so on.

Now I want to collect `ID` in `B` based on the following rule:

1. We can divide `A` into several blocks where the occurence(repetition) of element is >= 2. For example, the above `A` can be divided into 6 blocks and they are: `[7 7 7 7]`, `[8 8 8 8]`, `[2 2]`, `[3 3]`, `[5 5 5]`, and `[8 8 8]`. **Please be noted** that here we do not simply count the total occurence of each unique elements in `A`, that is, for example the element `8` totally occurs 7 times in `A` but it is in two different blocks: the second block `[8 8 8 8]` and the last block `[8 8 8]`.
2. Next I want to collect `ID` in `B` of first and last two pairs of elements of these blocks. For example for the first block `[ 7 7 7 7]`, the corresponding `ID` are `[50 20 32 91]`, so the first and last pairs are `[50 20]` and `[32 91]` respectively. More example, for the third block `[2 2]`, the `ID` are `[43 63]`, so the first and last pairs are both `[43 63]`. Further more, is the first pair and last pair are the same, we merge them, i.e., in this case we only output `[43 63]` rather than `[43 63], [43 63]`.

How can I perform this tricky collection?

So the function `get()` may take `A` and `B` as input, and return a 2-D array `C` of dimension `[number_of_pairs, 2]`, so each row of `C` stores a ID pair.

Comment: It can be a 2-D numpy array with dimension (No.pairs x 2)

Comment: Excuse me Nick, but I don't really understand your question. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Share your code attempting to solve the problem. What results are you getting?

Comment: @pazitos10 I tried an ugly version with for loop. It is slow and I am wondering whether it can be done in a faster way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pandas:

```
A = [7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 8, 8, 8]
B = [50, 20, 32, 91, 92, 93, 35, 72, 41, 42, 43, 63, 64, 85, 86, 56, 26, 27, 28, 89, 69]

import pandas as pd

results = []
df = pd.DataFrame(A, index=B)
for g in df.groupby(df[0].ne(df[0].shift()).cumsum()):
    idx = list(g[1].index)
    if len(idx) > 1:
        results.append(idx[:2])
    if len(idx) > 2:
        results.append(idx[-2:])

print(results)
```

This gives:

```
[[50, 20], [32, 91], [93, 35], [72, 41], [43, 63], [64, 85], [86, 56], [56, 26], [28, 89], [89, 69]]
```

Answer (score 0):

@pazitos10 I post myself answer here.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 2, 8, 8, 8])
B = np.array([50, 20, 32, 91, 92, 93, 35, 72, 41, 42, 43, 63, 64, 85, 86, 56, 26, 27, 28, 89, 69])

def get_pairs(A, B):
    pairs = []
    rg = A[:-1].shape[0]  # sliding window of 2
    for i in range(rg):
        if A[i] == A[i + 1]:  # find potential pair
            if i == 0:
                pairs.append([B[i], B[i + 1]])
            elif A[i] != A[i - 1]:
                pairs.append([B[i], B[i + 1]])
            elif i+1 == rg:
                pairs.append([B[i], B[i + 1]])
            elif A[i + 1] != A[i + 2]:
                pairs.append([B[i], B[i + 1]])
            else:
                pass
    return pairs
print(get_pairs(A, B))
```